# How to specify treatment in simper function

Tags: r, function

I want to do a **simpler test** for comparison between two communities that have two different treatments.Ddata matrix is contained plant Species as columns and rows are Year_Replication_Fertilizer (since this is a multi year study with replications and two fertilizer treatments). I need to know how I can specify the treatment in the simper function.

I used this code:

```
test<-read.csv("Fertilizer.csv")  #Remove site names
m<-as.matrix(test[,-1]) #Use site names as row names 
row.names(m)<- test[,1]  #install.packages("reshape2")
#install.packages("ggplot2") 
library(vegan) 
library(reshape2) 
library(ggplot2)  
simpcom<- simper(comm=m, group=m$Group).
```

In the original data frame the column contained treatments and years is called Group. But I think I removed the Group with that code that I gave. In siper test need to do comparison between treatments and between years to see the most contributors of the communities and how they are different from each other. Please help me how I can do that in the last row of the code I sent.

Comment: look at `?tapply()` It easily lets you apply functions to groups of values.

Comment: Thank you. But I am new to R coding and could not figure out how to write the index that is needed in tapply function.  I dot know how to specify value to this tapply(X, INDEX, FUN = NULL, ..., simplify = TRUE). What are X, and index? X is the name of my data frame? Index is different treatments?

Comment: when I applied this: simpcom<- simper(m, group=m[,1]) it worked and gave me the results of simper test. But I would like to see the contribution of species for each treatment. How can I know which results is related to which. Any body know this?

Comment: Have you looked at `summary(simpcom)`? The `cumsum` column is perhaps what you are after?